# SQL query to return more than one copy of same row, if hit on more than one where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, search, search-engine, record

Hitting a record based on multiple where clauses, I would like SQL to return a copy of the row being hit, for every where clause that matches.

```
c1 | c2 | c3

x    y    z
```

x,y,z : Would be return only once with a `where c1=x or c3=z`

I would like `where c1=x or c3=z` , to return, 2 copies of x,y,z

Can this be achieved?

**Why?**

I am trying to eliminate running multiple queries to get multiples of the same record to do prioritization.

I can and should get two copies of x,y,z if I run two queries, one for c1, and one for c3.

I want these 2 copies of x,y,z by design, but I want to run one query. With my implementation, I will run into situations where I will have to run more than 10 query trips to get what I am after... for one prioritized record.

I would rather run one single query, than 10.

Comment: Well, `UNION` is the obvious answer, but that's really just a way of doing multiple queries in a single statement...

Comment: @RBarryYoung, thanks, did not even think of that... I am fine with multiple queries actually, its the multiple round trips I don't like or want. Union should do it... thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would do it although it might not be as elegant as you'd like

```
SELECT c1,c2,c3 FROM [MyTableName] where c1=x 
UNION ALL 
SELECT c1,c2,c3 FROM [MyTableName] where c3=z
```

Comment: Thanks, let me give this a spin.

Comment: Works a charm. Would have liked one query, with a magic SQL option... but UNION works. I am not sure what performance impact UNION has... if anyone want to add anything on that subject.

Comment: There is no one answer to the performance impact of UNION. In some cases, a UNION could perform better than a single query with a non-optimal `where` clause. In other cases, it could perform worse.

Answer (score 0):

Already answered, but here is an alternative:

```
SELECT  c1,c2,c3
FROM    [MyTableName]
        JOIN (VALUES (1),(2)) t(n) 
            ON (t.n = 1 AND c1 = 'x') OR (t.n = 2 AND c3 = 'z');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t.*
FROM MyTable t
CROSS APPLY (
  VALUES
  (c1,'x'),
  (c2,'y'),
  (c3,'z')
) f(col,val)
WHERE col = val
```